# firebase cloud storage and firestore uploads for android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am working on a project which includes uploading data to Firebase cloud Storage and pictures to Firestore. I am working on the android platform.

The plan is to upload an image to Storage, while also uploading data Firestore. This step is fairly easy to do, but the problem arises in the error handling. Should either one of the uploads fail, I would like for both of them to fail or at least delete the other entry should that be ok.

My current best idea is to upload one of them in an onSuccessListener. Then perform the next upload. This just seems like a bad design. I cannot figure out a good solution to uploading both at the same time, and then evaluating the result afterwards without just introducing a lot of waiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont wanna have a nested code style, You may try Google Task API.

As both your uploads code will return a Task Object, you may call

```
Tasks.whenAllComplete(taskToFirestore, taskToStorage)
```

The above code will return a Task object so you can append `addOnSuccessListener()` or `addOnFailureListener()` to it. Then you can inspect the status of `taskToFirestore` and `taskToStorage` within the same listener

Comment: Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks